# Error con fecha de vencimiento

Tags: php

Tengo un script en cual calcula los dias por vencer un producto, funciona bien con fechas de hasta 15 dias, pero si el producto vence en diciembre de 2019 o el año proximo, no me cuenta bien los dias.

```
<?php

// fecha  = 2019-08-12 - fecha de elavotacion del producto
// vfecha = 2019-12-01 - vencimiento

$df='!Y-m-d';
$fechaInicio = DateTime::createFromFormat($df, $row['fecha']);
$fechaFinal  = DateTime::createFromFormat($df, $row['vfecha']);
$fechaHoy = new DateTime('today');
$totalDays = $fechaInicio->diff($fechaFinal)->d;   #Días totales entre las fechas dadas
$diffDays = $fechaFinal->diff($fechaHoy)->d;       #Días que faltan para que termine
$pastDays = $fechaInicio->diff($fechaHoy)->d;      #Días ya transcurridos
$msgInfo = $fechaFinal <= $fechaHoy ? "Finished": "$diffDays days left.";

echo $msgInfo;

// resultado:             15 days left
// resultado correcto:    102 days left

?>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Cuando utilizas el metodo "diff" este devuelve una instancia de "DateInterval" la cual tiene el atributo "days" que es el que debes consultar para obtener la diferencia de dias en lugar del atributo "d".

```
$totalDays = $fechaInicio->diff($fechaFinal)->days;  
$diffDays = $fechaFinal->diff($fechaHoy)->days;      
$pastDays = $fechaInicio->diff($fechaHoy)->days;
```

Documentacion: https://www.php.net/manual/es/class.dateinterval.php

Comment: Como añadido, es importante el parámetro `inverte`, para saber si la diferencia es positiva o negativa

Comment: No sabia eso, me he vuelto loco porque no me daba el resultado y no sabia si era por un metodo, una clase o no se... muchas gracias Salvatore, voy a leer el link que has dejado. Abrazo!